# Want to download and upload file from a folder inside the blob using new sdk - Azure.Storage.Blobs package

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, blob, azure-blob-storage

I want to download and upload a json file in a folder by using path and jsonContent in string for in new sdk - Azure.Storage.Blobs package. I am able to do so using old library as per below code -

UploadCode -

```
`public async Task<bool> UploadToBlob(string path, string jsonContentString)
    {
        CloudBlobContainer container = _cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(Constant.ContainerName);
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("dose/NotificationDefinition/dose_dosedailyreport.json");
        await blockBlob.UploadTextAsync(jsonContentString);
        return true;
    }`
```

Download Code -

```
public async Task<string> GetDataFromStorage()
    {
        CloudBlobContainer container = _cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(Constant.ContainerName);
        var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("dose/NotificationDefinition/dose_dosedailyreport.json");
        return await blockBlob.DownloadTextAsync();
    }
```

[image: Snapshot of Folder containing json file]

Comment: :)....Let me read the question first :P.

Comment: :D Sure @GauravMantri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code. Basically we're creating an instance of [`BlockBlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient?view=azure-dotnet) and calling it's [`Upload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient.upload?view=azure-dotnet) and [`Download`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.download?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlobBaseClient_Download) method for uploading and downloading.

```
    static void UploadDownloadTest()
    {
        var blobName = "dose/NotificationDefinition/dose_dosedailyreport.json";
        var containerName = "test";
        var connectionString = "UseDevelopmentStorage=true";
        var blockBlobClient = new BlockBlobClient(connectionString, containerName, blobName);
        var jsonContentString = "This is the data I wish to upload";
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonContentString)))
        {
            var httpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders()
            {
                ContentType = "application/json"
            };
            blockBlobClient.Upload(ms, httpHeaders);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Upload Successful!");
        var downloadResponse = blockBlobClient.Download().Value;
        using (var stream = downloadResponse.Content)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[downloadResponse.ContentLength];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            var responseData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            Console.WriteLine("Blob contents....");
            Console.WriteLine(responseData);
        }
    }
```